# Show that $M :=\{J\in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R}); J^2 = -I\}$ is a submanifold of $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

I want to show that:
$$ 
M := \{J \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid J^2 = -I \}
$$
is the submanifold of $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$, and I am given a hint to use Theorem 1.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $m,n,l \geq 0$. Suppose that $O$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $O'$ is a open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and the mappings $F: O \to O'$ and $G: O' \to \mathbb{R}^l$ are of the class $C^{\infty}$. Suppose that the points $a_0 \in O$, $\,b_0 \in O'$, and $c_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{l}$ satisfy the following conditions:
> (*i*) $F(a_0) = b_0$,
> (*ii*) $GF(O) = c_0$, and
> (*iii*) the sequence of linear mappings
> $$
> \mathbb{R}^n \xrightarrow{(JF)_{a_0}} 
> \mathbb{R}^m \xrightarrow{(JG)_{b_0}} \mathbb{R}^l 
> $$
> is exact. Then, there is a open set $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ that satisfies $b_0 \in W \subseteq O'$, and we have
> $$
> W \cap F(O) = W \cap G^{-1}(c_0) 
> $$
> and $W \cap F(O)$ will be a $C^{\infty}$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

However, I don't know how to use this theorem. In my opinion, I can consider $G$ as $\det$, and $\det^{-1} \{\pm{1}\}$ will be $M$, but I don't know what $J(\det)$ is.

Please help me!!!!!  I am Japanese, so I am not good at $\LaTeX$ and English. There may be a lot of mistakes in my context, please forgive me.

Comment: Caution: Property $det   =  \pm1$  characterizes a much larger manifold.

Comment: Thanks. What is J(det)??

Comment: $J(\det)$ is an undefined expression that you should never use.

Comment: Note that if $J^2 = -I$, then $(P^{-1}JP)^2 = -I$ for any $P\in GL(2n,\Bbb R)$. On a side note, are you sure that condition (iii) doesn't require exactness at both ends, too?

Comment: @MoisheKohan:  It seems to me that $J$ is being used in two seperate ways by the OP.  In the sense of a complex structure, I agree that $J(\det)$ is meaningless, but it seems the OP is using $Jf$ to refer to the Jacobian of a function $f$, as well.  In that context, $J(\det)$ is meaningful.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Oh, I see, you are probably right!